# hist2d plots with vmin/vax unknown until plotting with combined colorbar; previous solution not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am attempting to make plots of density in rows.  The challenging part, is that each of the plots must have the same color-scale min and max, and I do not know beforehand what the min and max are.  I must plot the values first in order to find out the min and max, remove those plots, and then make new ones with the determined min/max.

Something like this, but with hist2d and in rows (image from another S.O. page):
[image]

I've come up with a minimal working example based on [How to have one colorbar for all subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784201/how-to-have-one-colorbar-for-all-subplots), [vmin and vmax in hist2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66443606/vmin-and-vmax-in-hist2d)

and this solution from "SpinUp __ A Davis", which I don't see how I can implement with real data:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3)
for ax in axes.flat: # I don't see how to implement this part with real data
    im = ax.imshow(np.random.random((10,10)), vmin=0, vmax=1)

fig.colorbar(im, ax=axes.ravel().tolist())

plt.show()
```

but the best I can come up with is this, which doesn't work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np # only for MWE, not present in real file
# https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d.html

# getting min/max
fig, (ax0,ax1) = plt.subplots(nrows = 2, ncols = 1, sharex = True)
colormax = float("-inf")
colormin = float("inf")

h0 = ax0.hist2d(np.random.random(100), np.random.random(100))
colormax = max(h0[0].max(), colormax)
colormin = min(h0[0].min(), colormin)
h1 = ax1.hist2d(np.random.random(200), np.random.random(200))
colormax = max(h1[0].max(), colormax)
colormin = min(h1[0].min(), colormin)
# starting real plot, not just to get min/max
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 2, ncols = 1, sharex = True, figsize = (6.4,4.8))
i = 0
h = [h0, h1]
for ax in axes.flat: # I don't see how I can implement this
    im = ax.imshow(h[i], vmin = colormin, vmax = colormax)
    i += 1
fig.colorbar(im, ax= axes.ravel().tolist())
plt.savefig('imshow.debug.png')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create the histogram with `imshow`:

- You need to grab the histogram as the first of four values returned by `ax.hist2d`. So `h0, _, _, _ = ax.hist2d(...)`
- The histogram matrix needs to be transposed as it has x and y switched.
- `imshow` needs `origin='lower'` to have the lowest y at the bottom.
- `imshow` needs `extent=[...]` with the x and y ranges.

As you seem to want the x-axis shared (and not the y-axis), the histogram bins need to be calculated with the maximum x-range. Setting `(np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 11), 10)` splits the x-range in 10 bins, and uses the default 10 bins for y. In the example code, the x bins are shared, while the y bins are specific to each plot.

## Changes to code in question

The test code below also makes some changes:

- `turbo` colormap and extra colorbars to better see the difference
- Python's preferred way to make `for` loops (list comprehension to calculate min and max)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
import numpy as np

# first create some reproducible test data
np.random.seed(20240219)
x0 = np.random.random(100)
y0 = np.random.random(100)
x1 = np.random.random(100)
y1 = np.random.random(100)
xmin = min(x0.min(), x1.min())
xmax = min(x0.max(), x1.max())
bins = (np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 11), 10)

# dummy plot to calculate the min and max of the histograms
fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, sharex=True, figsize=(6.4, 4.8))
h0, _, _, img0 = ax0.hist2d(x0, y0, bins=bins, cmap='turbo')
cbar0 = fig.colorbar(img0, ax=ax0)
cbar0.ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))  # force integer ticks

h1, _, _, img1 = ax1.hist2d(x1, y1, bins=bins, cmap='turbo')
cbar1 = fig.colorbar(img1, ax=ax1)
cbar1.ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))  # force integer ticks

h = [h0, h1]
colormin = min(hi.min() for hi in h)
colormax = max(hi.max() for hi in h)

# starting real plot
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, sharex=True, figsize=(6.4, 4.8))
for ax, hi, yi in zip(axes.flat, h, [y0, y1]):
    im = ax.imshow(hi.T, vmin=colormin, vmax=colormax, origin='lower', aspect='auto',
                   extent=[xmin, xmax, yi.min(), yi.max()], cmap='turbo')
cbar = fig.colorbar(im, ax=axes.ravel().tolist())
cbar.ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))  # force integer ticks
plt.show()
```

[image: hist2d with common color scale via imshow]

## Using `np.histogram2d()`

To simplify the code, instead of `ax.hist2d`, `np.histogram2d` can be used.  This does all the calculations, without creating a plot.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
import numpy as np

# first create some reproducible test data
np.random.seed(20240219)
x0 = np.random.random(100) * 10
y0 = np.random.random(100) * 10
x1 = np.random.random(100) * 10
y1 = np.random.random(100) * 10
xmin = min(x0.min(), x1.min())
xmax = min(x0.max(), x1.max())
bins = (np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 11), 10)

h0, _, _ = np.histogram2d(x0, y0, bins=bins)
h1, _, _ = np.histogram2d(x1, y1, bins=bins)

h = [h0, h1]
colormin = min(hi.min() for hi in h)
colormax = max(hi.max() for hi in h)

# starting real plot
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, sharex=True, figsize=(6.4, 4.8))
for ax, hi, yi in zip(axes.flat, h, [y0, y1]):
    im = ax.imshow(hi.T, vmin=colormin, vmax=colormax, origin='lower', aspect='auto',
                   extent=[xmin, xmax, yi.min(), yi.max()], cmap='turbo')
cbar = fig.colorbar(im, ax=axes.ravel().tolist())
cbar.ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))  # force integer ticks
plt.show()
```

Comment: `colormin = min(h1.min() for hi in h)` did you mean `colormin = min(hi.min() for hi in h)`?

Comment: Oops. Typo. Thanks for catching that one. Now it should be corrected.